# validation issue with DOB field jquery

Tags: jquery

I have DOB enabled for registration

but if I enter the right Date from the calendar, it still displays an invalid date message. Here is the JS code

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

    var dataForm = $('#form-validate');
    var ignore = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_dob->isEnabled() ? '\'input[id$="full"]\'' : 'null'; ?>;
    
    dataForm.mage('validation', {
    <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.prop('id').search('full') !== -1) {
                var dobElement = $(element).parents('.customer-dob'),
                    errorClass = error.prop('class');
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                dobElement.find('.validate-custom').addClass(errorClass)
                    .after('<div class="' + errorClass + '"></div>');
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        },
        ignore: ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')'
    <?php else: ?>
        ignore: ignore ? ':hidden:not(' + ignore + ')' : ':hidden'
    <?php endif ?>
    }).find('input:text').attr('autocomplete', 'off');

});
</script>
```

Comment: Here is the website link - http://dev.rochway.com.au/customer/account/create/

Comment: When I enter value in all fields & select dob then click create account it shows error.

Comment: Video for reference - https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/8289014?key=4bf063d77576fd10e10ffabbaafe4c57

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] pages.   Not everyone is available all the time and sometimes a question can take a while for the relevant user to see and attempt an answer.  I great that you're checking on your question (so many just get abandoned), but please be patient.

Comment: Looking at your *rendered* html (on your website), your data-validate for dob is different from the other two:  `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"` `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"` but `data-validate="{&quot;validate-date&quot;:{&quot;dateFormat&quot;:&quot;d\/M\/Y&quot;},&quot;validate-dob&quot;:true}"`  so it could be that your validation code / plugin is not reading this correctly.
`

Comment: That makes sense, I am not sure how to fix this one.
Any advise ?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?